Issue with Merging 'dev' into 'main' Branch on GitHub
I'm experiencing issues when merging my 'dev' branch into the 'main' branch on GitHub. Here's the situation:
When I merge changes into the 'dev' branch, everything works fine. Only one commit is added, and there are no conflicts.
However, when I try to merge 'dev' into 'main', I encounter multiple problems:

The pull request shows many commits being added, not just the recent
ones from 'dev'.

Some of these commits are already present in 'main', but the files
from these commits are not included.

Conflicts arise during the pull request creation, which do not
happen when merging into 'dev'.


What could be causing these issues, and how can I fix them?

A tree structure of the repo and branches, together with the resulting errors would be great to help answer this question.

Run gitk --all to get a nice overview of your repository's history. For instance if main and origin/main are attached to different commits it means they are out of sync and you will see that instantly with gitk.

If your dev branch starts from an old commit you will benefit from rebasing it to the latest main. If you have not started using rebase yet (either interactive or non-interactive) you really should! There might be some learning curve but it is absolutely worth it. Make sure to test all commits (also outside of rebase, but especially after a rebase). Pushing after a rebase might need  forcepush.

This is probably because you haven't merged "main" branch into your "dev" branch for a long time.
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout dev
git merge main

Then resolve conflicts, do

git push

for dev branch, and try it again.
Hope it helps
